# Answer Mail can not include a Email Address

Tags: typo3, powermail

we have a little problem with the design of the mail templates for the sender. If we insert an email address with the link email function, this will be shown in the mail the recipient gets without the "@" and the persistent points.
How can we change this? What are we doing wrong.
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more info and/or a screenshot where you do the setting?

Comment: email-encryption relies on a small javascript-snippet that is always included. If you disable inclusion of javascript on your page completely, decryption is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your [email-address encryption](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html?highlight=spamprotectemailaddress#spamprotectemailaddresses) fails. Especially the replacement of `@` and `.`. maybe the replacements contain tags or other special characters which gets removed in the process of email generation.

Make sure you remove the email-encryption for mail rendering.
Something like:

```
mail = PAGE
mail {
  typeNum = 99
  config {
    spamProtectEmailAddresses = 0
    spamProtectEmailAddresses_atSubst = @
    spamProtectEmailAddresses_lastDotSubst = .
  }
}
```